# ¿Por qué me aparece este error en el controlador?

Tags: php, laravel

Al poner en la dirección

```
http://localhost:8000/almacen/articulo
```

aparece el siguiente mensaje:

```
ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:
Class sisVentas\Http\Controllers\ArticuloController does not exis
```

pero al poner

```
http://localhost:8000/almacen/categoria
```

me muestra la página

dónde está el error?

controlador de articulo

```
<?php

namespace sisVentas\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use sisVentas\Http\Requests;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use sisVentas\Http\Requests\ArticuloFormRequest;
use sisVentas\Articulo;
use DB;


class ArticuloController extends Controller
{
     public function __construct()
    {

    }
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request)
        {
            $query=trim($request->get('searchText'));
            $articulos=DB::table('articulo as a')
            ->join('categoria as c', 'a.idcategoria','=','c.idcategoria')
            ->select('a.idarticulo','a.nombre','a.codigo','a.stock','c.nombre as categoria','a.descripcion', 'a.imagen', 'a.estado')
            ->where('a.nombre','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
            ->orderBy('a.idarticulo','desc')
            ->paginate(7);
            return view('almacen.articulo.index',["articulos"=>$articulos,"searchText"=>$query]);
        }
    }
    public function create()
    {
        $categorias=DB::table('categoria')->where('condicion','=','1')->get();
        return view("almacen.articulo.create",["categorias"=>$categorias]);
    }
    public function store (ArticuloFormRequest $request)
    {
        $articulo=new Articulo;
        $articulo->idcategoria=$request->get('idcategoria');
        $articulo->codigo=$request->get('codigo');
        $articulo->nombre=$request->get('nombre');
        $articulo->stock=$request->get('stock');
        $articulo->descripcion=$request->get('descripcion');
        $articulo->estado='Activo';

        if(Input::hasFile('imagen')){
            $file=Input::file('imagen');
            $file->move(public_path().'/imagenes/articulos/',$file->getClientOriginalName());
            $articulo->imagen=$file->getClientOriginalName();        
        }
        $articulo->save();
        return Redirect::to('almacen/articulo');


    }
    public function show($id)
    {
        return view("almacen.articulo.show",["articulo"=>Articulo::findOrFail($id)]);
    }
    public function edit($id)
    {

        $articulo=Articulo::findOrFail($id);
        $categorias=DB::table('categoria')->where('condicion','=','1')->get();
        return view("almacen.articulo.edit",["articulo"=>$articulo,"categorias"=>$categorias]);
    }
    public function update(ArticuloFormRequest $request,$id)
    {
        $articulo=Articulo::findOrFail($id);

        $articulo->idcategoria=$request->get('idcategoria');
        $articulo->codigo=$request->get('codigo');
        $articulo->nombre=$request->get('nombre');
        $articulo->stock=$request->get('stock');
        $articulo->descripcion=$request->get('descripcion');

        if(Input::hasFile('imagen')){
            $file=Input::file('imagen');
            $file->move(public_path().'/imagenes/articulos/',$file->getClientOriginalName());
            $articulo->imagen=$file->getClientOriginalName();        }
        }
        $articulo->update();
        return Redirect::to('almacen/articulo');
    }
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $articulo=Articulo::findOrFail($id);
        $articulo->estado='Inactivo';
        $articulo->update();
        return Redirect::to('almacen/articulo');
    }

}
```

controlador de categoria

```
<?php

namespace sisVentas\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use sisVentas\Http\Requests;
use sisVentas\Categoria;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use sisVentas\Http\Requests\CategoriaFormRequest;
use DB;


class CategoriaController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request)
        {
            $query=trim($request->get('searchText'));
            $categorias=DB::table('categoria')->where('nombre','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
            ->where ('condicion','=','1')
            ->orderBy('idcategoria','desc')
            ->paginate(7);
            return view('almacen.categoria.index',["categorias"=>$categorias,"searchText"=>$query]);
        }
    }
    public function create()
    {
        return view("almacen.categoria.create");
    }
    public function store (CategoriaFormRequest $request)
    {
        $categoria=new Categoria;
        $categoria->nombre=$request->get('nombre');
        $categoria->descripcion=$request->get('descripcion');
        $categoria->condicion='1';
        $categoria->save();
        return Redirect::to('almacen/categoria');

    }
    public function show($id)
    {
        return view("almacen.categoria.show",["categoria"=>Categoria::findOrFail($id)]);
    }
    public function edit($id)
    {
        return view("almacen.categoria.edit",["categoria"=>Categoria::findOrFail($id)]);
    }
    public function update(CategoriaFormRequest $request,$id)
    {
        $categoria=Categoria::findOrFail($id);
        $categoria->nombre=$request->get('nombre');
        $categoria->descripcion=$request->get('descripcion');
        $categoria->update();
        return Redirect::to('almacen/categoria');
    }
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $categoria=Categoria::findOrFail($id);
        $categoria->condicion='0';
        $categoria->update();
        return Redirect::to('almacen/categoria');
    }



}
```

rutas:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('almacen/categoria','CategoriaController');
Route::resource('almacen/articulo','ArticuloController');
```

Comment: El mensaje de error es dice que no tienes el archivo: `ArticuloController`

Comment: @Shassain si, pero si tengo el archivo ArticuloController

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos era un corchete que me sobraba en el controlador Articulo